# Intellij IDEA gradle jetty plugin can not start

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, jetty

I use  gradle  to develop a spring4 & mybatis3 project under jdk8 with IDEA,but when I run jettyRun,It just run a backgroung task to do something I don't know... It does not start the jetty plugin no matter how long I wait, but when I use the command in CMD (windows), it's normal.

So I am really confused, does anyone know the reason or meet this before?
[image: 1.jpg]